# Botones y funciones a la vez

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos botones diferentes con sus respectivas funciones, pero lo que quiero hacer es tener un solo botón y que haga ambas funciones. Primero una y que cuando le hagas click haga la otra. Gracias.

```
var boton_apagar=document.createElement("button");
zona_un_boton[0].appendChild(boton_apagar);
boton_apagar.setAttribute("id","boton_apagar");
boton_apagar.innerHTML="OPACAR";
boton_apagar.addEventListener("click", apagar_imagenes);

var boton_encender=document.createElement("button");
zona_un_boton[1].appendChild(boton_encender);
boton_encender.setAttribute("id","boton_encender");
boton_encender.innerHTML=" NO OPACAR";
boton_encender.addEventListener("click", encender_imagenes);

function apagar_imagenes(){
    /* Ayuda: la función document.getElementsByClassName (funciona igual que getElementsByTagName)
    nos da un array con todos los elementos que  pertenecen a una clase, 
    si no utiliza  getElementById, pero tendrás que hacerlo 8 veces una para cada imagen */
    var imagenes=document.getElementsByClassName("fotos");
    for(var i=0;i<3;++i){
        imagenes[i].style.opacity="0.5";
    }
}

function encender_imagenes(){
    var imagenes=document.getElementsByClassName("fotos");
    for(var i=0;i<3;++i){
        imagenes[i].style.opacity="1";
    }
}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio, ¿podrías editar la pregunta y aclarar lo que quieres decir con "primero una y que cuando hagas click haga la otra"? Lo que me refiero es si tiene que ejecutarse una función antes de hacer nada, y la segunda siempre que ser haga click, o lo que quieres es que si le das una vez haga lo de la primera función, si le das dos veces haga lo de la segunda función, si le das 3 veces haga otra vez lo de la primera función, etc. Sospecho que te refieres a esto último, pero para que no de lugar a dudas.

Comment: En el boton cuando ejecutes la funcion , debes enviar algo para validar a que funcion quieres que vaya o siempre sera cuando haga el primer click, ejecute la funcion 1 y cuando haga el segundo ejecute la funcion 2 ? siendo ese el caso tienes que validar el numero de clic en el boton ya ejecutar tus funciones.

Comment: lo que quiero es que si le doy una vez haga lo de la primera función, si le das dos veces haga lo de la segunda función, si le das 3 veces haga otra vez lo de la primera función, etc.

Comment: `$(".boton").click(function(){
    alert('Ha hecho click sobre el boton'); 
    return true; // TIP: esto no es necesario de todas formas
});` con esto puedes validar los clic crea un contador y dependiendo del valor envias a la funcion, debes reiniciar el contador despues de cada cierto clic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar de un estado a otro, necesitas tener alguna "memoria" de en qué estado están las imágenes. Esto puede ser desde una variable booleana que te indica si son visibles, una clase que si está en la imagen es que es visible, y si la clase no está es que es translúcida...

En tu caso, como estás cambiando la opacidad, puedes usar el valor de la opacidad para saber en que estado está la imagen.

Si la opacidad es 0.5 la cambias a 1, y si la opacidad es 1 la cambias a 0.5

```js
var zona_un_boton0 = document.getElementById("zona_un_boton0");
var boton_apagar = document.createElement("button");
zona_un_boton0.appendChild(boton_apagar);
boton_apagar.setAttribute("id","boton_apagar");
boton_apagar.innerHTML="OPACAR/NO OPACAR";
boton_apagar.addEventListener("click", cambiarImagenes);

function cambiarImagenes(){
    var imagenes = document.getElementsByClassName("fotos");
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (imagenes[i].style.opacity === "0.5") {
           imagenes[i].style.opacity = "1";
        } else {
           imagenes[i].style.opacity = "0.5";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.fotos {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<img class="fotos" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg"/>
<img class="fotos" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg"/>
<img class="fotos" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg"/>
<div id="zona_un_boton0"></div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias a sido super útil tu información gracias de verdad.